# Ember observe nested array property

Tags: ember.js

I want to observe a nested property. I have the following Ember Array:

```
specifications: [
  {
    title: "specification name",
    filters: [
      {
        title: "example"
        checked: false
      },
      {
        title: "example 2",
        checked: true
      }
    ]
  },
  ...
]
```

I want to create a computed property:

```
activeFilters: (->
  Ember.computed.filterBy('specifications.@each.filters', 'checked', true),
).property('specifications.@each.filters')
```

The active filters property is not working, I tried several combinations of property methods, but none worked.

Is the property I am trying to create actually possible?

Comment: Do you mean `specifications.filters.@each`?

Comment: I noticed that you never accept answers. Consider closing some of your questions.

Comment: I will do that right now.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible. The thing is that for it to work you can't use a JavaScript array, you need an `Ember.ArrayProxy` and then you can access its special properties: http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.ArrayProxy.html

```
specifications: Ember.ArrayProxy.create({
  content: [
    {
      title: "specification name",
    },
  ]
});
```

So, you'll have something like:

```
oneSpecChangedCheck: function() {
  // don't know which, but someone changed
  var s = this.get('specs');
  // loop and process
  return s;
}.property('specs.@each.checked'),
```

http://emberjs.jsbin.com/zohuzo/2/edit?html,js,console,output

Comment: Good point about the ArrayProxy, though my javascript array was for example purposes. The array I am working with comes from  Ember data.  

I created a jsbin to mimick my issue: http://emberjs.jsbin.com/mijise/5/edit?html,js,output  

How can I create the computed property `checkedFilters` based on all filters with `checked == true`. The nesting of filterS inside specificationS makes it hard for me to get my head around.

Comment: I couldn't find a way to make it work with `filterBy`, that would return the elements "directly". I quote "directly" because if you look at the source code of the function you'll see that its using `@each` too.

Comment: I'm rectifying, it is not possible to do it with `filterBy`. The closest would be to use a custom `filter`, but in my opinion it would me more complicated than a computed property because those go from the outer layers to the inner layers and you want the opposite. The same fiddle I posted has code that will guide you to the same conclusion.